# LINQ dynamic expression in order by clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, predicatebuilder

I have the following query:

```
 product = product.OrderByDescending(d => d.ProductAttributeItem
                            .Where(ai => ai.AttributeItem.AttributeId == (int)DefaultAttributes.Name)
                            .SelectMany(p => p.AttributeItem.AttributeItemValue)
                            .Any(o => EF.Functions.Like(o.Value, "%apple%") || EF.Functions.Like(o.Value, "%samsung%"))
```

which in fact is working perfectly fine. `product` is a rather complex query built with many predicates based on input filters. Here we are interested in the `Any()` part of the query, specifically the predicate part - how `EF.Functions.Like(o.Value, "%apple%") || EF.Functions.Like(o.Value, "%samsung%")` can be generated dynamically.

I am already using some predicate builder extension methods in our project and they are working great for non nested cases like:

```
var condition = PredicateBuilder.True<AttributeItemValue>();

if(filters.OnlyActivated)
     condition = condition.And(product => product.IsActive);

product = _context.Product.Where(condition);
```

So I have tried to build the predicate in loop:

```
var aivCond = PredicateBuilder.True<AttributeItemValue>();
foreach (var s in searchQueryArray)
{
      aivCond = aivCond.Or(f =>
      EF.Functions.Like(f.Value, "%" + s + "%"));
}
```

So now the `aivCond` is of type `Expression<Func<AttributItemValue, bool>` but this can't be used to replace the lambda in `Any()` because it expects `Func<TSource, bool>`. Tried to compile it this way `aivCond.Compile()` but the following error occurs:

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[AttributeItemValue,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[AttributeItemValue,System.Boolean]]' of method 'Boolean Any[AttributeItemValue](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AttributeItemValue]
```

I have also tried to build the lambda expression from string:

```
var filter = "f => EF.Functions.Like(f.Value, \"%apple%\") || f => EF.Functions.Like(f.Value, \"%samsung%\")";

                var options = ScriptOptions.Default
                    .AddReferences(typeof(AttributeItemValue).Assembly)
                    .AddReferences(typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EF).Assembly)
                    .AddReferences(typeof(DbFunctions).Assembly)
                    .AddImports("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore");

                Func<AttributeItemValue, bool> filterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Func<AttributeItemValue, bool>>(filter, options);
```

with no luck.

I know I missing knowledge for expression trees, compiling and invocation for delegates so any help(and explanation) would be really appreciated!

**EDIT / SOLUTION**

So there is a solution thanks to the help of [Richard Deeming](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124386/richard-deeming).
He was right for starting the predicate with False. I stupidly copy/pasted code from a different method without noticing.

As about his second comment, adding `AsQueryable()` allows to pass an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` which is pretty obvious but not for me. This translates fine and the compiler is ok.

Anyway, there is another approach, using LINQKit's `AsExpandble()` method and the inbuilt `Compile()` method in the Expression class and as described in [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx):

> Compile is an inbuilt method in the Expression class. It converts the Expression<Func<Purchase,bool> into a plain Func<Purchase,bool> which satisfies the compiler. Of course, if this method actually ran, we'd end up with compiled IL code instead of an expression tree, and LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework would throw an exception. But here's the clever part: Compile never actually runs; nor does LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework ever get to see it. The call to Compile gets stripped out entirely by a special wrapper that was created by calling AsExpandable, and substituted for a correct expression tree.

So the code would look like this:

```
product = product.AsExpandable().OrderBy(d => d.ProductAttributeItem
          .Where(ai => ai.AttributeItem.AttributeId == (int)DefaultAttributes.Name)
          .SelectMany(p => p.AttributeItem.AttributeItemValue)
          .Any(aivCond.Compile()));
```

Thank you everyone for the help and I hope this question helps somebody lost in the code... !

Comment: Looks like you have the opposite problem: `PredicateBuilder` is creating a normal `Func` rather than an `Expression`. Where did you get this class from?

Comment: @Charlieface, I have it from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/) which is an early version of the `PredicateBuilder` now included in LINQKit

Comment: **NB:** For an `or` condition, you'll want to start with `False` rather than `True`; otherwise, the predicate will always match all records.

Comment: Have you tried `.SelectMany(p => p.AttributeItem.AttributeItemValue).AsQueryable().Any(aivCond)`? That should let you pass in an `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`.

Comment: @RichardDeeming, thank you very much for the great guidance! You've really helped a ton! If you add your comments as an answer I would be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you just need to use [the `AsQueryable` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.asqueryable) on the collection to pass in the `Expression<Func<TItem, bool>>` as the filter.

```
product = product.OrderByDescending(d => d.ProductAttributeItem
    .Where(ai => ai.AttributeItem.AttributeId == (int)DefaultAttributes.Name)
    .SelectMany(p => p.AttributeItem.AttributeItemValue)
    .AsQueryable().Any(aivCond);
```